# Selenium IDE: e.match is not a function

Tags: selenium-ide

Each time I tried to run any script in Selenium IDE, I got error:

```
e.match is not a function
```

since I've spent much longer than I should looking for a solution, I'm gonna post it here so that the next person having the same issue can find it on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"runScript" takes the argument as "Target" parameter, not "Value". 
Empty "target" field is what causes the (very badly handled) error.